# How to purge (delete) credit card numbers stored on Magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, payment-methods, security

We used the 'Saved CC' payment method in our Magento 1.9.1.0 store and now we would like to delete the credit card numbers for security reasons.

### What is the easiest procedure to delete all credit card numbers?

---

---

**UPDATE ON SEPTEMBER 21st, 2018:**

I just tried to do that. I go to phpMyAdmin in the cPanel. There are 2 databases:

> 1. mySITE_mySITE
> 2. information schema

I highlight either, click on SQL, and enter the following lines (one at a time):

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;


UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;
```

But then it gives me the following Errors:

```
Error
SQL query:
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL
MySQL said:  
#1146 - Table 'mySITE_mySITER.sales_flat_order_payment' doesn't exist



Error
SQL query:
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL
MySQL said:  
#1109 - Unknown table 'sales_flat_order_payment' in information_schema
```

---

---

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**Another UPDATE on September 21st:**

it turns out that all that I needed to do was to **add mg_ in front of the code** like this:

```
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;


UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;
```

**And now it works!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encrypted credit card numbers are stored in the `cc_number_enc` column of the `sales_flat_order_payment` table. With this SQL query you can delete them all:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
```

To delete all credit card data, do the same with the other columns that start with `cc_`:

- cc_type
- cc_number_enc
- cc_last4
- cc_owner
- cc_exp_month
- cc_exp_year

Comment: I tried to do this but I think I must be doing it wrong because I get Error messages and I don't think it actually executes. Would you please look at my update above in the original post?

Comment: I added mg_ and it works now. Thanks! :o)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the save card data for security purpose in Magento 2 due to PCI compliance?

Comment: @Ketan yes, do not use the "saved cc" payment method, there are plenty alternatives with third party providers

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information :)

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to use the same command on `sales_flat_quote_payment` as credit card numbers are stored in this table as well.

Comment: I tried to do this but I think I must be doing it wrong because I get Error messages and I don't think it actually executes. Would you please look at my update above in the original post?

Comment: I added mg_  in front of the code and it works now. Thanks! :o)