# Getting Error messages when trying to delete CC numbers via phpMyAdmin

Tags: delete, credit-card

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I am now trying to delete stored credit card numbers from our database using phpMyAdmin as per my question here:

[How to purge (delete) credit card numbers stored on Magento 1.9.1.0?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138280/how-to-purge-delete-credit-card-numbers-stored-on-magento-1-9-1-0)

I made me a list of SQL commands to run:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;


UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;
```

*I think I must be doing something wrong...this is how I go about doing this:*

There are 2 databases:

> mySITE_mySITE
>
> information schema

I highlight either, click on SQL, and enter the following lines (one at a time):

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;


UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;

But then it gives me the following Errors:
```

> Error SQL query: UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET
> cc_number_enc=NULL MySQL said:
>
> ## 1146 - Table 'mySITE_mySITE.sales_flat_order_payment' doesn't exist
>
> Error SQL query: UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET
> cc_number_enc=NULL MySQL said:
>
> ## 1109 - Unknown table 'sales_flat_order_payment' in information_schema

**What do I need to do to make this work?**

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that all that I needed to do was to add mg_ in front of the code like this:

```
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_order_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;


UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_number_enc=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_type=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_last4=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_owner=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_month=NULL;
UPDATE mg_sales_flat_quote_payment SET cc_exp_year=NULL;
```

**And now it works!**